# How many messages can a queue hold?

Tags: celery

In Celery, what is the upper bound limit of the number of messages in a queue?

How many messages can wait in a queue in order to be prefetched/consume by a worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue length depends from broker(and message length). For example, if you are using RabbitMQ as broker, you can expect millions of messages(I saw hundreds of thousands in practice). You can make simple load testing using RabbitMQ management plugin(monitor resources).

[This thread](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Max-messages-allowed-in-a-queue-in-RabbitMQ-td26063.html) can be helpful.